# NSRange Error while using it for lookup

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to find if a substring is present in a given string or not and I am using NSRange in a block.
But I am getting an error and I have no idea where I am going wrong.
Could someone explain this?

```
-(AddressCard *) lookup:(NSString *)tempName{


    NSUInteger result = [book indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSRange *range = [[obj name] rangeOfString:tempName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range != NSNotFound) {
            return YES;
        }
        else return NO; //Keep looking
    }];
    if (result != NSNotFound) {
        return book[result];
    }
    else{
    return nil;
    }
}
```

The error message is: Initializing 'NSRange *' (aka 'struct _NSRange *') with an expression of incompatible type 'NSRange' (aka 'struct _NSRange')

Found the answer. NSrange is struct and not an object. I will accept the answer after 10 minutes

Comment: What "error"?  Please help us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

must be `NSRange range` instead of `NSRange *range` . `NSRange` is not an interface type, it's a `struct`

```
 NSRange range = [[obj name] rangeOfString:tempName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I should be sleeping now.